# How to correctly handle images with Django and CloudFiles?

Tags: django, celery, rackspace, cloudfiles

In my particular case I'm using Rackspace CloudFiles with [sorl-thumbnails](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail). It seems to download images from CloudFiles slowly. I have 1 worker for handling requests and another one for celery tasks.

Looked for existing solutions and it seems there is no such one at the moment.

Maybe I missed something? How should it be done the right way?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your architecture/purpose? Code would be even more awesome. I'd love to help but I'm not sure what you're doing. Are you using CloudFiles as your KeyValue store in sorl-thumbnails? Are you putting the images on the CDN?

Comment: I have a load balancer and 2 servers for django. Celery is on a separate server. Sorl-thumbnails were setup to use local KeyValue storage and each time cache was cleaned up it took time like 5k ms to handle the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't going to solve your problem, but there are some things to note/think about:

Remote object storage (Amazon's S3, Rackspace's CloudFiles) is going to be slower than local filesystem access. This depends on what you're doing of course and who's fetching the thumbnail. For users, downloading from a CDN is going to be faster than from a server. It may serve you well to do the thumbnail creation locally on an SSD backed server then upload to CloudFiles, distributing it over the CDN. Rackspace now has [beefier SSD based instances with much greater IOPS](http://developer.rackspace.com/blog/welcome-to-performance-cloud-servers-have-some-benchmarks.html).

The [sorlery](https://github.com/aidanlister/sorlery) module takes great care to queue thumbnail creation with Celery (for use with remote object storage) and avoid filesystem access.

On another note, `sorl-thumbnail` hasn't seen development in over a year with LOTS of pull requests and issues sitting out on GitHub. Have you thought about using [`easy-thumbnails`](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) with [`django-cumulus`](http://django-cumulus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: I came with the conclusions :-) Now I am changing sorl-thumbnail to easy-thumbnails and already use django-cumulus. Will write here about the results :-)

Comment: easy-thumbnails with django-cumulus work great. Thanks a lot!